# cloned NSArray gets mutated when I change the original array

Tags: nsarray, xcode7, allocation

In my application, I have a view where I apply filters. So when I come back and change the filters but do not press apply button and just back button, I want the original filters to apply back just the ones before I changed them now.

Eg. Filters - City - A, B, C - Applied - Saved A,B,C filters
Came again Filters - City - D,E - Back button pressed - Regain A,B,C filters

For this what I am doing is just when the viewdidload for filterview is opened, I save the filters array into a clone array

```
clonedFiltersData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[WMGFilterManager sharedManager] arrayForType:type]];
```

this is working fine but when I change something in 
[[WMGFilterManager sharedManager] arrayForType:type]

like remove some filters or something, it actually gets removed from the original array. Can anyone tell how to initiate the array so that it is not affected by its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add the copyItems:YES option to the initWithArray. As in this example;

```
  NSArray *deepCopyArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:someArray copyItems:YES];
```

You want a deep copy, not a shallow one (which copies pointers).